# Finding a degree 8 polynomial with one root given. (Octagon)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> > Question: The vertices of a regular octagon, shown on the Argand diagram in the figure shown, represent the roots of a complex degree $8$ polynomial. One root is shown at the point $A$, $1 + 0i$.
> >
> > Write the polynomial in the form $p(z) = (z-(a+bi))^n + q$
> >
> > [image]

---

I have not attempted much but my thoughts are that roots come in conjugates but that doesn't really help me in this because I get the same root (1).   Other than that I am really stuck on this question.

Comment: The roots don't come in conjugates, as clearly seen in the diagram. Instead, imagine transferring the origin  to the center of this octagon(q comes from there), and circumscribe the octagon in a circle centered at the origin. Now find the angles of each point with respect to the x-axis, and multiply all the $e^{i\theta}$ together. That would give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the roots are symmetrical about $y=x$, 
then write down the roots one by one:

$\color{red}{1}$, $i$

$1+\sqrt{2}$, $(1+\sqrt{2})i$,

$2+\sqrt{2}+i$, $1+(2+\sqrt{2})i$,

$2+\sqrt{2}+(1+\sqrt{2})i$, $\color{blue}{1+\sqrt{2}+(2+\sqrt{2})i}$

Centre of roots $\displaystyle=
\frac{\color{red}{1}+\color{blue}{1+\sqrt{2}+(2+\sqrt{2})i}}{2}$

then $\displaystyle p(z)=\left[ z- \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i) \right]^{8}+q$

$p(1)=q-68-48\sqrt{2}=0$, therefore

$$p(z)=\left[ z- \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i) \right]^{8}+68+48\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got the roots by them being symmetrical around x?

Comment: $1$ and $i$ differ by distance of $\sqrt{2}$ so the next real root is $1+\sqrt{2}$ and the next root is translated by $1+i$, and then further translate by $i\sqrt{2}$. Flipping real & imaginary parts gives the others.  Pick up any two opposite roots in order to find the centre.

Answer (score 1):

The image is obviously symmetric to the diagonal. Then the side length of the octagon is $\sqrt2$ and the midpoint at $z_0=(1+\frac12\sqrt2)(1+i)$. From that you can compute the radius as
$$
r=|z_0-A|=|\frac12\sqrt2+(1+\frac12\sqrt2)i|=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}
$$
so that the equation becomes
$$
(z-z_0)^8+r^8=0
$$
because if the center is shifted to the origin, there are not roots on the axes, which gives the $+r^8$.

Comment: How did you get the midpoint?

Comment: It is obviously on the diagonal, and has both coordinates $1+\frac12s$ as midpoint of the edges on the x- and y-axes, where $s=\sqrt2$ is the side-length obtained as distance from $1$ to $i$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a formula from the tyod you asked for. This formula is for a unit cycle that you move but in your case you need also to rotate.

$$
 (\frac{z}{e^\frac{2\pi i}{8}}-(\frac{2+\surd{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}))^8 =1
$$